# Can all loops (for, while, do while) be expressed in terms of one another in java ?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

I understand that we can express a do while loop in the form of a while loop and a while loop in the form of for loop. So the following conversions are possible (Correct me if I am wrong):

For -> While

While -> For

Do-While -> While

Do-While -> For

But I am not sure if I can convert a while loop to do while as while loop doesn't necessarily run atleast once. Is there a way around to convert a while loop to do-while?

Comment: "Is there a way around to convert a while loop to do-while?" => Guard it with an `if` before entering the `do`-`while`.

Comment: Yes, it's possible for all except the for-each loop (`for Item item : iterable`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily go from while to do-while. For example, just add a boolean set to true at first, and in the loop condition, do like "condition OR boolean". Then in the loop, set your boolean to false. Here could be a way of doing it :

```
boolean condition = true;
while (condition) {
  condition = doThings();
}
```

It's maybe not the best to do it, but it works perfectly only with adding a boolean variable.
EDIT : My bad, I corrected my answer. Now it is really a do-while loop.

---

I did another answer, which is more clear for me, I thing it really depends on your preferences. Here it is :

```
boolean bool = true;
while (yourCondition || bool) {
   if (bool) {bool = false;}
}
```

For your curiosity, it happens (pretty much often I think) that compilers convert all types of loops into only one. So all loops are equivalent, you just need to find a way to do it :) .

Comment: I simplified it a bit. So the `doThings()` is the thing you want to do at least once. If it returns true you keep doing it until it returns false. That's the do while

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't understand that you changed my answer ... I'm not sure to understand your changes, but anyway ^^

Comment: Just remove my edit if you don't feel comfortable with it. I thought it would be better to support you than coming up with my own answer that almost states the same^^

Comment: As I didn't feel totally comfortable with it, I added so that there are both of our answers :)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have an interface

```
interface LoopInfo {
    Runnable init();
    BooleanSupplier goOn();
    Runnable next();
}
```

with a given instantiation

```
LoopInfo myInfo;
```

then this is a `for`-loop

```
for (myInfo.init().run(); myInfo.goOn(); myInfo.next().run()) {
    // loop code
}
```

the equivalent while-do loop

```
myInfo.init().run();
while (myInfo.goOn()) {
    // loop code
    myInfo.next().run();
}
```

and the equivalent do-while loop

```
myInfo.init().run();
do {
    if (myInfo.goOn()) {
        // loop code
    }
    myInfo.next().run();
} while (myInfo.goOn());
```

So yes, they can be equivalently transferred between each other.